# Adding prime symbol (') to ggplot2 axis label using expression()

Tags: ggplot2

I have the following code snippet that should (once complete) plot `u_prime` and `v_prime` on the `log2(x + 1)` scale using `expression`:

```
p <- ggplot(df_uv_prime, aes(x = u_prime, y = v_prime)) + geom_point(colour = "blue") +
            labs(x = expression(log[2](u^{...} + 1)), y = expression(log[2](v^{...} + 1))) +
            xlim(0, 1) +
            ylim(0, 1)
```

However adding `'` in place of `...` doesn't work, as R expects a closing `'`.

Is there a `base` R solution without having to resort to any packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description of the desired outcome, one option is to enclose the single quote or backtick (not sure which one you're using) in double quotes and add 'connectors' (*) or 'spaces' (~) to either side, e.g. backtick with space on x axis, single quote with connector on y axis:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = hp, y = disp)) +
  geom_point(colour = "blue") +
  labs(x = expression(log[2](u*"`"~ + 1)),
       y = expression(log[2](v*"'"* + 1)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This works. I was using the single quotation mark BTW.  Is there any benefit to using connectors vs. spacers?

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. I don't know of any benefit in using connectors instead of spaces (except for the 'one less space' thing); as far as I can tell they are functionally equivalent